# Tableau Desktop - Auto-sizing Dashboard Without Scrollbars

Tags: dashboard, tableau-desktop

When I create a Tableau dashboard, by default the dashboard fits to the size of the window. The sheets on the dashboard will shrink to fit the dashboard, and will get scroll bars if needed. I want to set up the dashboard so the sheets never get scroll bars, and the dashboard will scroll if necessary

The primary solution i've found is to set a custom size to the dashboard, with a large minimum vertical size. This results in the dashboard having a permanent scroll bar, which works, but isn't ideal. If i want to use the download feature to grab a screenshot of my dashboard, it will be padded with a large amount of white space at the end.